# Why I get +1 of my string length when I use gets?

Tags: ruby

I have to make a algorithm to check if a phrase is a palindrome, but I could notice the method gets increase my string length.
But I'm not sure what's going on with my code..

```
puts "Phrase: "
# before
# str = gets.to_s
str = gets.chomp


def palindrome(string)
    split_string = string.split("")
    reversed = []
    string.size.times { reversed << split_string.pop }
    str = reversed.join.delete(" ")
    str2 = string.delete(" ")
    if str == str2
        puts "Is a palindrome!!!"
    else
        puts "Not a palindrome!"
    end
end

palindrome("a santa lived as a devil at nasa")
# Right 

palindrome("It's not a palindrome")
# Right

palindrome(str)
# I put any palindrome phrase like "race car" and I get the wrong result
```

Comment: There is no need to convert the return value of `gets` to a `String`. Hint: what does the `s` in `gets` stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just to use the .chomp after the gets.
I'm feeling so dumb...

```
str = gets.chomp
```

Without it the gets method includes a newline character at the end

Comment: *"counts the line as well"*  could be better worded as *"includes a newline character at the end"*